# SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle : Already attached to lifecycleOwner

Tags: android, android-savedstate

I am using [AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory) to use [SavedStateHandle](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateHandle) in a View Model with non-empty constructor. But I get an Illegal State Exception saying it is already attached to a life-cycle owner(see below). When I use `SavedStateViewModelFactory` instead, it works fine but it does not support non-empty constructors and is a final class.

**TestStateAFragment**

```
class TestStateAFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() : TestStateAFragment {
            val fragment = TestStateAFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelable("arg_a", TestState.TestStateA)
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            return fragment
        }
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel : TestStateAViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val factory = TestStateAViewModelFactory(activity as SavedStateRegistryOwner)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(TestStateAViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

**TestStateAViewModel**

```
class TestStateAViewModel(val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    var countStateObserver : BehaviorRelay<Int> = BehaviorRelay.create<Int>()

    private var count : Int = 0
    set(value) {
        field = value
        savedStateHandle.set("count", field)
        countStateObserver.accept(field)
    }
    init {
        savedStateHandle.get<Int>("count")?.let {
            count = it
        }
    }

    fun incrementCount() {
        count += 1
    }

    fun decrementCount() {
        count -= 1
    }
}
```

**TestStateAViewModelFactory**

```
class TestStateAViewModelFactory(
    savedStateRegistryOwner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    bundle : Bundle? = null
) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(savedStateRegistryOwner, bundle) {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(
        key: String,
        modelClass: Class<T>,
        handle: SavedStateHandle
    ): T {
        return TestStateAViewModel(handle) as T
    }
}
```

**Exception :**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lifecycleviewmodel, PID: 14295
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached to lifecycleOwner
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle(SavedStateHandleController.java:43)
        at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:67)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:177)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:145)
        at com.example.lifecycleviewmodel.fragment.states.a.TestStateAFragment.onCreate(TestStateAFragment.kt:47)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1197)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1080)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:119)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at com.example.lifecycleviewmodel.TestActivity.onStart(TestActivity.kt:34)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1470)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7170)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3071)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Can someone please point out where the problem is? Thank you.

EDIT : Following are the links to the issues raised  for this particular bug. This is marked as fixed, expected to release this week 09/30-10/05.
[Issue-1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141225984) [Issue-2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141289014)

Comment: This problem occurs due to the new SavedStateHandleController class. It seems to have been added in this commit: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/002e4fa8e74e8aea45dca1055a255e20691f4c56

Comment: If I am not wrong, this commit was in version 1.0.0-alpha05. The issue currently persists in this version, there is an issue filed for this.

Comment: @ashwinmahajan please link the issue

Comment: @ZacSweers Done, added in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in ViewModel Saved State version [1.0.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#viewmodel-savedstate-1.0.0-beta01).
Find issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141225984).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but might help someone else.
Use
`private val viewModel by activityViewModels()`